# Magento 2.2.2 - Include external/internal Javascript for specific CMS page

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, widgets, social-buttons

I need to integrate addthis widget on CMS page. In my custom them I created xml file `cms_page_view.xml` which resides at `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Themename/Magento_Theme/layout/`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-1234567890" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I can see the social sharing icons appearing on that CMS page, but as I have included it from xml, it appears on all CMS page of the store

I tried including below xml from `Design` tab in `Layout Update XML` in admin

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="shop-by-project">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-1234567890" />]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

It gives exception `Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'reference': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1`

- How do I include external and internal javascript for specific CMS
  page making sure it does not load in other CMS and product pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `cms_page_view.xml` handle, you can try cms page specific layout handle as shown below:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------  +
|    Page Identifier    |  Layout Handle Name         |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------+
| Home                  | cms_index_index_id_home     |
| about_us              | cms_index_index_id_about_us |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

i.e, append your page identifier with `cms_index_index_id_` and you get your specific cms page layout update handle.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I have around 20 CMS pages which supports social sharing. So does it mean I have to create 20 xml files with different page identifiers?

Comment: From your question, what I understand is, you need to integrate some js with a specific cms page. In that case, you need to use the specific layout handle as I mentioned in my answer. If you want to add this functionality for 5 cms pages out of 20 cms pages, then you need to create 5 specific layout handle files to achieve this. Or else you need to do this via event observer method, I believe

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong (you seem to be using Magento 1 syntax), there is no container or block named `head`.

Try this:

```
<head>
    <script src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-1234567890" src_type="url" />
</head>
```